# What does the parameter 'classwt' in RandomForest function in RandomForest package in R stand for?

Tags: r, random-forest

The help page for `randomforest::randomforest()` says:

> "classwt - Priors of the classes. Need not add up to one. Ignored for regression."

Could setting the `classwt` parameter help when you have heavy unbalanced data,  ie. priors of classes differs strongly ?

How should I set `classwt` when training a model on a dataset with 3 classes with a vector of priors equal to (p1,p2,p3), and in test set priors are (q1,q2,q3)?

Comment: I'm not sure about your second question, but `classwt` I believe is used when sampling from your data, such that each sample for each tree is drawn from your classes with those probabilities (after normalization).

Comment: strata yields the same performance as classwt and is easier to control, check out this guide on SO: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/r-package-for-weighted-random-forest-classwt-option/158030#158030

Comment: @joran that's stratafication your're describing. Classwt is used to weight samples when to find optimal break point for node split and to define node prediction during training.

Comment: may my old comments also haunt me four years later :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> could setting classwt parameter help when you have heavy unbalanced data - priors of classes differs strongly?

Yes, setting values of classwt could be useful for unbalanced datasets. And I agree with joran, that these values are trasformed in probabilities for sampling training data (according Breiman's arguments in his original article).

> How set classwt when in training dataset with 3 classes you have vector of priors equal to (p1,p2,p3), and in test set priors are (q1,q2,q3)?

For training you can simply specify

```
rf <- randomForest(x=x, y=y, classwt=c(p1,p2,p3))
```

For test set no priors can be used: 1) there is no such option in `predict` method of randomForest package;  2) weights have only sense for training of the model and not for prediction.

Comment: As I understand priors (p1,p2,p3) are characteristic of general population, not the specific training dataset. If I want to predict classes in the test dataset and I know that classes probabilies in the set are (q1,q2,q3) than setting classwt=c(q1,q2,q3) should help random forest to explore training space in better way.

Comment: No, these class weights are specific for the training set only. For example, if you have balanced training set, in general there is no need to use `classwt` parameter. But at the same time you can have unbalanced test set, and I expect that changing class weghts will not improve test set prediction in such a case. In another words, using `classwt` you may increase prediction accuracy for one of the classes and simultaneously descrease for another. You can play with this parameter a bit and look on OOB set prediction statistics, for example.