# How to calculate class weights for Random forests

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I have datasets for 2 classes on which I have to perform binary classification. I chose Random forest as a classifier as it is giving me the best accuracy among other models.
Number of datapoints in dataset-1 is 462 and dataset-2 contains 735 datapoints. I have noticed that my data has minor class imbalance so I tried to optimise my training model and retrained my model by providing class weights. I provided following value of class weights.

```
cwt <- c(0.385,0.614) # Class weights
ss <- c(300,300) # Sample size
```

I trained the model using following code

```
tr_forest <- randomForest(output ~., data = train,
          ntree=nt, mtry=mt,importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE,
          maxnodes=mn,sampsize=ss,classwt=cwt,
          keep.forest=TRUE,oob.prox=TRUE,oob.times= oobt,
          replace=TRUE,nodesize=ns, do.trace=1
          )
```

Using chosen class weight has increased the accuracy of my model, but I am still doubtful whether my approach is correct or is it just a coincidence. How can I make sure my class weight choice is perfect?

I calculated class weights using following formula:

> Class weight for positive class = (No. of datapoints in
>   dataset-1)/(Total datapoints)
>
> Class weight for negative class = (No. of datapoints in
>   dataset-2)/(Total datapoints))
>
> ```
>  For dataset-1 462/1197 = 0.385
>  For dataset-2 735/1197 = 0.614
> ```

Is this an acceptable method, if not why it is improving the accuracy of my model. Please help me understand the nuances of class weights.

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: @desertnaut Perfect is the word that can be used for your answer. It is really helpful my friend. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I make sure my class weight choice is perfect?

Well, you can certainly not - *perfect* is the absolutely wrong word here; we are looking for useful *heuristics*, which both improve performance and make sense (i.e. they don't feel like magic).

Given that, we do have an independent way of cross-checking your choice (which seems sound indeed), albeit in Python and not in R: the scikit-learn method of [`compute_class_weight`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html); we don't even need the exact data - only the sample numbers for each class, which you have already provided:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

y_1 = np.ones(462)     # dataset-1
y_2 = np.ones(735) + 1 # dataset-2
y = np.concatenate([y_1, y_2])
len(y)
# 1197

classes=[1,2]
cw = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes, y)
cw
# array([ 1.29545455,  0.81428571])
```

Actually, these are your numbers multiplied by ~ 2.11, i.e.:

```python
cw/2.11
# array([ 0.6139595,  0.3859174])
```

Looks good (multiplications by a constant do not affect the outcome), save one detail: seems that scikit-learn advises us to use your numbers *transposed*, i.e. a 0.614 weight for class 1 and 0.386 for class 2, instead of vice versa as per your computation.

We have just entered the subtleties of the *exact definitions* of what a class weight actually is, which are not necessarily the same across frameworks and libraries. scikit-learn uses these weights to weight differently the misclassification cost, so it makes sense to assign a *greater* weight to the *minority* class; this was the very idea in a [draft paper](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf) by Breiman (inventor of RF) and Andy Liaw (maintainer of the `randomForest` R package):

> We assign a weight to each class, with the minority class given larger weight (i.e., higher misclassification cost).

Nevertheless, this is **not** what the `classwt` argument in the `randomForest` R method seems to be; from the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest):

> **classwt**     Priors of the classes. Need not add up to one. Ignored for regression.

"*Priors of the classes*" is in fact the analogy of the class presence, i.e. exactly what you have computed here; this usage seems to be the consensus of a related (and highly voted) SO thread, [What does the parameter 'classwt' in RandomForest function in RandomForest package in R stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112678/what-does-the-parameter-classwt-in-randomforest-function-in-randomforest-packa); additionally, Andy Liaw himself has [stated](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289769.html) that (emphasis mine):

> The current "classwt" option in the randomForest package [...] is **different** from how the official Fortran code (version 4 and later) implements class weights.

where the official Fortran implementation I guess was as described in the previous quotation from the draft paper (i.e. scikit-learn-like).

I used RF for imbalanced data myself during my MSc thesis ~ 6 years ago, and, as far as I can remember, I had found the `sampsize` parameter much more useful that `classwt`, against which Andy Liaw (again...) has [advised](https://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/help/08/05/12088.html) (emphasis mine):

> Search in the R-help archive to see other options and why you probably **shouldn't** use classwt.

What's more, in an already rather "dark" context regarding detailed explanations, it is not at all clear what exactly is the effect of using *both* `sampsize` *and* `classwt` arguments together, as you have done here...

---

To wrap-up:

- What you have done seems indeed correct and logical
- You should try using the `classwt` and `sampsize` arguments *in isolation* (and not together), in order to be sure where your improved accuracy should be attributed

Comment: I liked your idea of taking either side (sampsize or classwt). I will do the remaining experiments. Thanks for your elaborated reply.